# Can you create a percentile rank in SQL based on multiple criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to create a percentile ranking of customers based on their finances. Financial score goes from 0-1000. This creates a percentile,

```
  SELECT AccountID, FirstName, LastName, FinancialScore,
     PERCENT_RANK() OVER(
     ORDER BY FinancialScore) AS PctRank
  FROM CustomerTable
  ORDER BY Financial DESC


AccountID  FirstName LastName FinancialScore  Income Score    Rank
1          John       Doe      900            4510
2          Jane       Doe      345            1000
```

but I'm wondering if I can have the percentile take into account multiple measures of financial standing with a range other than 0-1000?

Edit: I also just noticed the percentile rank is only basing the rank off of the first 2 numbers (eg. 99 is higher than 970)?

Comment: If you want to base the percentile on multiple measures then you either need to add further ordering e.g. `PERCENT_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY FinancialScore, FirstName)`, or you need to apply a partition, e.g. `PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName ORDER BY FinancialScore)`. It is not entirely clear from the question which one you want (if any).

Comment: If `99` is appearing higher than `970` it is because your number is stored as a string, therefore alphabetic sorting is going on, which works on a character by character basis, i.e. first character of both is 9, so equal ranking at first, then the next characters are `9` and `7`, since `7` is lower than `9`, `970` appears before `99`. In the same way `Aardvark` appears before `ant`. If they are both numbers, and you want to treat as numbers, then [store them as numbers!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @GarethD I don't have the authority to change how the data is stored, it's done by another company, is there a workaround?

Comment: Convert it to a number before you order it e.g. - `ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(INT, FinancialScore)`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on the desired results, but you could rank the product of Financial and Income Scores... These could be weighted as well

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([AccountID] varchar(50),[FirstName] varchar(50),[LastName] varchar(50),[FinancialScore] varchar(50),[Income Score] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'John','Doe',900,4510)
,(2,'Jane','Doe',345,1000)

Select * 
      ,Ranked = dense_rank() over (order by try_convert(int,FinancialScore) * try_convert(int,[Income Score]) desc)
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
AccountID   FirstName   LastName    FinancialScore  Income Score    Ranked
1           John        Doe         900             4510            1
2           Jane        Doe         345             1000            2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it as int to order properly:

```
;with tableA as
(select 1 as AccountID,'John' as FirstName,'Doe' as LastName,'970' as FinancialScore,4510 as Income_Score Union
select 2 as AccountID,'Jane' as FirstName,'Doe' as LastName,'99' as FinancialScore,1000 as Income_Score)

SELECT AccountID, FirstName, LastName, FinancialScore,
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(FinancialScore as int)) AS PctRank
FROM tableA
ORDER BY FinancialScore DESC
```

If you need other measures/fields to impact the rank, then you can add them either in partition or order by.

1. partition_by_clause divides the result set produced by the FROM clause into partitions to which the function is applied. If not specified, the function treats all rows of the query result set as a single group.
2. order_by_clause determines the logical order in which the operation is performed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percent-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Hope this helps.